Adding a new target to a driver variable
Can anyone advise on how to add a new target to a driver variable (like the commented-out code below)?
var = driver.variables.new()
var.name = var_name

var.targets[0].id_type = 'OBJECT'
var.targets[0].id = obj1
var.targets[0].data_path = data_path1

# new_target = var.targets.new()  # AttributeError: bpy_prop_collection: attribute "new" not found
# new_target.id_type = 'OBJECT'
# new_target.id = obj2
# new_target.data_path = data_path2


You need change the variable type first and the targets length depends on each type
var.type = "LOC_DIFF"
# Now the target length is 2
var.targets[1].id = ..


Thank you! I incorrectly assumed I could add an arbitrary number of targets.

You can only have one target per variable, but you can have an arbitrary number of variables
